# Extract span between starttext and endtext in txt file, exactly n times

Tags: awk, sed

I want to extract only the n first occurrences of

```
starttext(
some text
endtext)
```

in text file F.

I've tried experimenting with sed:

```
sed - '/starttext/,/endtext/p' inputfile
```

... this will give me ALL the ranges between starttext and endtext in inputfile. But I only want the first n ranges...

File F:

```
starttext(
sometext1
more text
endtext)
starttext(
sometext2
pineapple
endtext)
starttext(
sometext3
orange
banana
endtext)
starttext(
sometext4
some other text
endtext)
starttext(
sometext5
coconut
endtext)
starttext(
sometext6
endtext)
```

Fake command

```
sed - '/starttext/,/endtext/p' ((get the top 3 instances) inputfile
```

Epected output:

```
starttext(
sometext1
more text
endtext)
starttext(
sometext2
pineapple
endtext)
starttext(
sometext3
orange
banana
endtext)
```

I was asked to provide the following:

> Also tell us if there can be nested ranges, or overlapping ranges, or starts with no end or ends with no start.

There is always an endtext after each starttext. Ranges are not nested or overlapping.

> Also do you want to look for the start and end as regexps or strings?

Strings

> And do you want to do a full-line match or partial line or something else?

I want the full line match from starttext to the full line of endtext with all the text (several lines) in between.

Comment: How do you expect a simple script to insert text like `more text` or `pineapple` that does not appear in the original file?

Comment: I don't, that was a copy and paste error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```sh
awk -v n=3 'index($0, "starttext"){f=1; if(c++ == n) exit}
            f; index($0, "endtext"){f=0}' ip.txt
```

If you don't have any lines outside of these two markers (based on given sample), you can also use:

```sh
awk -v n=3 'index($0, "starttext") && c++ == n{exit} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want everything from the beginning of the file up to, and including, the nth `endtext`.

Not pretty but it gets the job done.

```
head -$(grep -nm $n endtext $file | tail -1 | grep -o [0-9]*) $file
```

Where `$n` is the number of text spans you want and `$file` is the text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v n=3 '
    $0=="starttext(" { f=1 }
    f { print; if ($0=="endtext)") { f=0; if (++c==n) exit } }
' fileF
starttext(
sometext1
more text
endtext)
starttext(
sometext2
pineapple
endtext)
starttext(
sometext3
orange
banana
endtext)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable with brace expansion from the bash shell.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^starttext(/;/^endtext)/p'{,,} q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

The comma `,` inside the braces duplicates what ever is at the left side.
So the first count is the pattern `'/starttext/;/endtext/p'` and two commas `,,` inside the curly braces equals 3 patterns.

---

The above brace expansion expands to.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^starttext($/;/^endtext)$/p' '/^starttext($/;/^endtext)$/p' '/^starttext($/;/^endtext)$/p' q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

Or `mapfile` from the bash shell

```
mapfile -d')' -t array < file.txt

IFS=')'; printf '%s\n' "${array[*]:0:3})"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/starttext/,/endtext/{H;g;s/endtext/&/3;T;s/.//p;q}' file
```

Gather up the matching occurrences in the hold space.

If the end delimiter matches n times (in this case 3), remove the introduced newline, print the result and quit.